# Unicode for icon not working properly, it shows broken icon

Tags: html, unicode

In HTML, I'm showing printer icon using Unicode `&#128438;` , but it is not displaying correct. Also i have used `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: You'll need a font that supports it, and [not many do](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5b6/fontsupport.htm)

Comment: @HuguesM. That list is only for the server it's running on - it states on the page "This only includes fonts installed on this server." Arial on Windows 10 has that icon, also Liberation Sans on Ubuntu 16.04. So a few more than shown on that page.

Comment: I Used &#9113; and it gives an icon like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge9zv.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&#9113;` instead of `&#128438;`

Refer https://unicode-table.com/en/